# Can't count PostgeSQL requests in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I know how to do it in db shell, but I need to do it in the code in which file and where should I place `print(len(connection))`. Maybe I need to do something else?

Comment: `print(len(connection.queries))`

Comment: I know about this command, the thing that i don't is where i should place it. manage.py?@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: it is with `.queries`, not `len(connection)`. For what do you want to use this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to place it in your views, but be sure your querysets are evaluated.
But I would recommend you to use django-silk, it's much more powerful kit for your goal.